# Why is there vs Why are there

Tags: grammar

1. Why ‘is’ there so much violence in that movie?
2. Why ‘are’ there so much violence in that movie?

Which one is correct?

Answer (score 1):

First answer: *violence* is uncountable (and therefore singular), so the verb is *is*, not *are*.

Second answer: for many English speakers (but not all), *there is* (usually in the form *there's*) has become invariable, and they use it even for a plural complement. Eg *There's a lot of people in the square*. Not everybody would say this, but many would, and most people don't notice anything odd about it.

Even among people who say *there's so many people*, not all would be comfortable turning it round, and would say *Why are there so many people?*; but some would by happy with *Why is there so many people?*

In any case, none of this second answer affects your question (I just mentioned it for completeness): any English speaker would say *Why is there so much violence?*

Comment: THANK YOU! But what if we say “Why is/are there so many violence and nudity in Game of Thrones?”, what should I use? ‘Is’ or ‘are’? There are two nouns/subjects.

Comment: Much*. Apologies for the mistake.

Comment: @Strider: I think most people would still use _is_ there - probably because _violence and nudity_ almost becomes a single item in this sort of discussion. But _are_ would not be wrong.